# After changing LVM, I have "residue" of old PV's

Tags: lvm

I used to have an LVM LV based off of two smaller disks. I introduced a new, much larger disk, migrated the data, and retired the old disks.

Everything works fine. The 3Tb disk `/dev/sdb1` is fully dedicated to `chronicle_vg`, which in turn is fully dedicated to `chronicle_lv`, which is mounted on my file system.

However, `system-config-lvm` (the gui) shows something I can't see the source of in `lvm` (the command-line tool). Where does this come from, how can I get rid of it?

Here's my current `lvm` setup:

```
jan@monolith ~ $ sudo lvm
[sudo] password for jan: 
lvm> pvs
  PV         VG           Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/sda5  ssd_vg       lvm2 a--  119,00g    0 
  /dev/sdb1  chronicle_vg lvm2 a--    2,73t    0 
lvm> vgs
  VG           #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree
  chronicle_vg   1   1   0 wz--n-   2,73t    0 
  ssd_vg         1   1   0 wz--n- 119,00g    0 
lvm> lvs
  LV           VG           Attr      LSize   [also Pool etc...]
  chronicle_lv chronicle_vg -wi-ao---   2,73t                                           
  root_lv      ssd_vg       -wi-ao--- 119,00g                                           
lvm>
```

But, in the GUI, I get extra LV's in the VG:
[image]
Before my reconfiguration, the `chronicle_vg` was made up of 4 equally-sized PV's (partitions) on two identical 750Gb disks. I suppose these are the ones marked "89425 extents". I have no idea where the smaller ones come from, or what sizes they represent. Could there be some form of cache or residual config I could flush or rebuild?

My goal here is really simply to get `system-config-lvm` to agree with `lvm`, because I'm positive that it tells the truth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are seeing the extents that made up the previous PV's. Run `pvs --segments` to have `lvm` agree with `system-config-lvm`. See http://www.redhat.com/magazine/009jul05/features/lvm2/ for more information.

Comment: Huh. You're right. So, I shouldn't attempt to get rid of that segmentation, to have my PV be a single segment?

Comment: I doubt it's having any adverse effect on your system. If you really wanted to get rid of it, I think you'd have to create a new volume (on a large enough disk) and manually mirror/copy the data across, then remove the old volume (and optionally pvmove the new volume back to the original disk).

Comment: Nah, that's fine. I just didn't know that (single) volumes still appeared as composites. Thanks!